# Extending Faker in a gem, where do I put the YAML file?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, faker

I have a gem which uses Faker to help build mock data. I'd like to add a new class that generates a new category of stuff, using the same syntax Faker itself uses. The first half is easy, I simply define the class, and make sure my gem loads the file:

```
# lib/faker/restaurant.rb
module Faker
  class Restaurant < Base
    class << self
      def name
        parse('restaurant.name')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So far, so good. Now, to describe what values can come out of this, I create a YAML file:

```
faker:
  en:
    restaurant:
      suffix: [Cafe,Restaurant]
      name:
        - "#{Name.first_name}'s #{suffix}"
```

So, the actual question: **Where does this file go, and what name should it have?** If this were a Rails application, it would be `config/locales/faker.en.yml`. In a gem, that doesn't appear to work - there isn't actually a 'config' directory, for one thing, but creating it for this purpose doesn't help, I get:

```
> Faker::Restaurant.name
I18n::MissingTranslationData: translation missing: en.faker.restaurant.name
```

Comment: in the faker gem itself, these are in a 'locales' directory: https://github.com/stympy/faker/tree/master/lib/locales

Comment: @dax True. I tried putting mine in `<my_gem>/lib/locales` to no effect, though.

Comment: maybe a missing requirement, as in `lib/faker.rb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. Special thanks to **dax**, whose comments prodded me in the right direction.

Faker uses the I18n gem for localization (which is why the YAML files live in a 'locales' directory). This means that I needed to add my custom YAML to the I18n load path. It doesn't matter exactly where the files are, as long as they're added to the load path. In my case, I put it at `lib/faker/locales/en-US.yml`, and added that entire directory to the load path, thus:

**lib/my_gem.rb:**

```
I18n.load_path += Dir[File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)), 'faker/locales', '*.yml')]
require "faker/restaurant"
```

Any `.yml` files I put in that directory should be loaded and available to Faker.

Side note: I also needed to change the YAML format slightly - it should be

```
en:
  faker:
    <stuff>
```

rather than with faker at the top level, as I had it.